# I am trying to learn AJAX, but my app (not a particularly useful one) keeps giving me the error message that I set for it (something went wrong)

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to learn AJAX on my own by writing a (not particularly useful) app where I put in an ID and an "amount of ice cream" through Javascript. It sends this to a PHP script on my XAMPP server by means of AJAX and queries the SQL database according to the provided ID to see how much ice cream there is. It is then supposed to send back, again through AJAX, the ID provided as well as the total amount of ice cream. I keep, however, getting the error message "something went wrong" that I set in the code.

I will provide below all the information I think is relevant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Response Ajax Application</title>
    
    <script src="ajax.js" defer></script>

</head>
    
<body onload="getServerText()">
    
    <h1>here is the text returned by the server: </h1>
    
    <div id="myPageElement"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
function query($id) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "ice_cream_inventory";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    $sql = "SELECT amount_of_ice_cream FROM ice_cream_inventory WHERE name=$id;";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $mysqli->close();
    return $result;
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$preExistingNumber = query($id);
$number = $_GET['number'] + $preExistingNumber;
$text = "This is the response text from the server. Your ID is $id. You have a total of $number buckets of ice cream in my freezer.";
echo $text;
?>
```

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return req;
}

var http = getXMLHTTPRequest();

function getServerText() {
  var id = parseInt(prompt('enter your ID: '));
  var number = parseInt(prompt('enter a number: '));
  var myurl = 'textserevr.php';
  var myRand = parseInt(Math.random() * 999999999999999);
  var modurl = myurl + '?rand=' + myRand + '&id=' + id + '&number=' + number;
  http.open('GET', modurl, true);
  http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
  http.send(null);
}

function useHttpResponse() {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
    if (http.status == 200) {
      var mytext = http.responseText;
      document.getElementById('myPageElement').innerHTML = mytext;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('myPageElement').innerHTML = 'something went wrong';
    }
  }
}
```

[image: database1]

[image: database2]

Thanks

All I have tried is looking for what the error might be, but was unable to find it.